# Iterate over PSObject properties in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have this `PSObject` (from XML):

```
bool : {IsActive, ShowOnB2C, ShowOnB2B, IsWebNews}
str  : {id, ProductId, GroupName, Unit...}
int  : {ProductIdNumeric, Prices_SalesOne, Prices_Treater, Prices_B2C...}
arr  : {EnvironmentBrands, Catalogs, NavisionLevels}
long : long
```

I would like to iterate over the properties without using the property names, for instance `bool`.

I have tried to index into the object like this:

```
$document[0]
```

But that gives me nothing, but it does not cause any errors either.

`Select-Object` kind of works, but then I have to use the property names, and I don't want that.

```
$documents | Select-Object bool,str
```

`ForEach` do not iterate the properties.

```
$documents | ForEach {
    $_.name
}
```

returns doc and that is the name of the tag (XML) holding the bools, ints, and strings.

Comment: You might have a look at `Get-Member` cmdlet.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

This is possible using the intrinisc member [`PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members) ([see also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.properties)):

```
$documents.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name
    $_.Value
}
```

This won't work with certain PowerShell-created objects (`PSObject`s) that contain "NoteProperties" (properties of type `NoteProperty`).

[See this answer for a method that covers all property types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47930107/3905079).

Comment: $documents.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object iterates the original object although $documents is a subset of the original XML object `$documents = $responseContent.ChildNodes.result.doc`

Comment: This won't work for PSCustomObjects that have NoteProperty members instead of Property members like the object output from a cmdlet. You have to use the get-member syntax shown in the other answer below to cover all variations of object properties.

Comment: Thanks @Blaisem I've updated this answer with a link to the other.

Comment: Thank you, the hidden property was killing me.

Comment: The `.PSObject` is an intrinsic member and is documented here: [about_intrinsic_members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.3)

Answer (score 30):

I prefer using `foreach` to loop through PowerShell objects:

```
foreach($object_properties in $obj.PsObject.Properties)
{
    # Access the name of the property
    $object_properties.Name

    # Access the value of the property
    $object_properties.Value
}
```

Generally, `foreach` has higher performance than `Foreach-Object`.

And yes, `foreach` is actually different than `Foreach-Object` under the hood.

Answer (score 17):

You might need NoteProperty too with Get-Member.

```
$documents | Get-Member -membertype property,noteproperty | 
  Foreach name
```

EDIT: type "properties" seems a more generic catchall

```
$documents | get-member -type properties | % name
```

EDIT:  dump out all the values:

```
$obj = ls test.ps1
$obj | Get-Member -Type properties | foreach name | 
  foreach { $_ + ' = ' + $obj.$_ }

Attributes = Normal
CreationTime = 06/01/2019 11:29:03
CreationTimeUtc = 06/01/2019 15:29:03
Directory = /Users/js
DirectoryName = /Users/js
Exists = True
Extension = .ps1
FullName = /Users/js/test.ps1
IsReadOnly = False
LastAccessTime = 06/05/2019 23:19:01
LastAccessTimeUtc = 06/06/2019 03:19:01
LastWriteTime = 06/01/2019 11:29:03
LastWriteTimeUtc = 06/01/2019 15:29:03
Length = 55
Name = test.ps1
```

An alternative way without "| foreach name", that needs extra parentheses:

```
$obj | Get-Member -Type properties | 
  foreach { $_.name + ' = ' + $obj.($_.name) }
```

Another take which results in an array that's easier to work with, and might be good for objects converted from json:

```
$a = '{ prop1:1, prop2:2, prop3:3 }' | convertfrom-json     
$a

prop1 prop2 prop3
----- ----- -----
    1     2     3

$a.PSObject.Properties | select name,value

name  value
----  -----
prop1     1
prop2     2
prop3     3
```

Comment: This is the general answer. The ``$object.psobject.properties`` only works with objects output from a cmdlet. PSCustomObjects use NoteProperties and will require the ``| gm -MemberType NoteProperty`` syntax, or ``-MemberType properties`` which will work for objects with either properties or noteproperties.

Answer (score 7):

Like [stej mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688708/powershell-iterate-over-psobject-properties#comment62854565_37688708), there is the [`Get-Member`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849928.aspx) cmdlet with a `-MemberType` parameter you can use:

```
$documents | Get-Member -MemberType Property | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name
}
```

Comment: How do you get the value with get-member?

Comment: @Brain2000 You could parse it from `$_.Definition` or use `$_.Name` to reference the property of your object: `$documents.($_.Name)`. But I would rather go for the solutions of [briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37688746/11942268) and [Kolob Canyon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46590477/11942268).

Answer (score 4):

I use the following command to enumerate the properties and put them in a table:

```
$Object.PSObject.Properties | Format-Table @{ Label = 'Type'; Expression = { "[$($($_.TypeNameOfValue).Split('.')[-1])]" } }, Name, Value -AutoSize -Wrap
```

I wrote the following function around this, that iterates through nested properties as well.

```
function Enumerate-ObjectProperties {
    param (
        [psobject] $Object,
        [string] $Root
    )

    Write-Output $($Object.PSObject.Properties | Format-Table @{ Label = 'Type'; Expression = { "[$($($_.TypeNameOfValue).Split('.')[-1])]" } }, Name, Value -AutoSize -Wrap | Out-String)

    foreach ($Property in $Object.PSObject.Properties) {
        # Strings always have a single property "Length". Do not enumerate this.
        if (($Property.TypeNameOfValue -ne 'System.String') -and ($($Object.$($Property.Name).PSObject.Properties))) {
            $NewRoot = $($($Root + '.' + $($Property.Name)).Trim('.'))
            Write-Output "Property: $($NewRoot)"
            Enumerate-ObjectProperties -Object $($Object.$($Property.Name)) -Root $NewRoot
        }
    }
}

Enumerate-ObjectProperties $YourObject
```

However please do keep in mind that some object are constructed somewhat typical, in the sense that they have 'loops' in their nesting. Subproperties that refer to parent objects.
An example being:

```
Get-Date 'somebogusdata'
Enumerate-ObjectProperties $Error[0]
```

This will create a loop.
You could of course add a 'depth' parameter to add a depth counter, specifying you only want to go to a certain depth.
That would look something like this:

```
$script:Level = 1
function Enumerate-ObjectProperties {
    param (
        [psobject] $Object,
        [int32] $Depth = 1,
        [string] $Root
    )

    Write-Output $($Object.PSObject.Properties | Format-Table @{ Label = 'Type'; Expression = { "[$($($_.TypeNameOfValue).Split('.')[-1])]" } }, Name, Value -AutoSize -Wrap | Out-String)

    foreach ($Property in $Object.PSObject.Properties) {
        # Strings always have a single property "Length". Do not enumerate this.
        if (($Property.TypeNameOfValue -ne 'System.String') -and ($($Object.$($Property.Name).PSObject.Properties)) -and ($Level -le $Depth)) {
            $NewRoot = $($($Root + '.' + $($Property.Name)).Trim('.'))
            $Level++
            Write-Output "Property: $($NewRoot) (Level: $Level)"
            Enumerate-ObjectProperties -Object $($Object.$($Property.Name)) -Root $NewRoot
            $Level--
        }
    }
}

Enumerate-ObjectProperties -Object $Error[0] -Depth 2
```