# Read JSON file through PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I need list of value which `change_flag` is `TRUE`.

In the list, I need eg "ZIPZOOMBIN_VERSION", "KERNEL_VERSION" which I am using as an array list in another PowerShell file

```
{
  "ZIPZOOMBIN_VERSION": {
    "change_flag": "TRUE",
    "localpath": " "
  },
  "KERNEL_VERSION": {
    "change_flag": "TRUE",
    "localpath": " "
  },
  "ACTIVE_MQ": {
    "change_flag": "FALSE",
    "localpath": " "
  }
}

list = [ZIPZOOMBIN_VERSION, KERNEL_VERSION]
```

Comment: Do you have any influence on the created json? I think it should be designed as an array of elements that have three subelements (name, change_flag, localpath). Then it would be way easier to evaluate :-)

Comment: No I do not have control.I need to consume json

Answer (score 0):

The key is to iterate over the properties of an object, that you do not know in advance. You can read more about it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37688708/11942268) question. You can do it like this:

```bsh
$content = @"
{
  "ZIPZOOMBIN_VERSION": {
    "change_flag": "TRUE",
    "localpath": " "
  },
  "KERNEL_VERSION": {
    "change_flag": "TRUE",
    "localpath": " "
  },
  "ACTIVE_MQ": {
    "change_flag": "FALSE",
    "localpath": " "
  }
}
"@
$myObject = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $content
$myList = @()
foreach ($property in $myObject.PSObject.Properties) {
    if ($property.Value.change_flag -ilike "TRUE") {
        $myList += $property.Name
    }
}
$myList
```

The content of `$myList` will be the two strings `ZIPZOOMBIN_VERSION` and `KERNEL_VERSION`.