# PSObject nested iteration over multiple properties

Tags: powershell, iteration

Let's say I have an array of PSObjects with several properties that are hierarchical.
Something like

```
@{
   'city' = 'CityName'
   'street' = 'StreetName'
   'House' = 'NNN'
   'Apartment' = 'MMM'
}
```

How do I do nested iteration over these properties? Like, city first, then street etc.?

1. City A

   - Street a

     - House 1

       - Apartment 1
       - Apartment 2
     - House 2

       - Apartment 1
       - Apartment 2
   - Street b House 1

...
etc...

What comes to mind either create lists of unique values for each property and then iterate through them filtering corresponding objects, or use multiple Group-Objects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate over PSObject properties in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688708/iterate-over-psobject-properties-in-powershell)

Comment: @zett42 Yeah, I saw that post and no, it doesn't answer. It iterates through all properties, while I need to iterate nested according to hierarchy. I figured this out - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($groupCity in $myObject | Group-Object 'city')
   Write-Host($groupCity.Name)
   foreach($groupStreet in $groupCity.Group | Group-Object 'street'){
      Write-Host($groupStreet.Name)
      <#and so on...#>
   }
}
```